# MySQL Full-text search in ZF2 using TableGateway

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2

Is it possible to run a full-text search MySQL query? How may I do it using the TableGateway? Thanks in advance.

Comment: mysql FT only works on isam tables prior to 5.6 release. IMHO -Sphinx or Solr is what should be used instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
$table = new \Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway('table', $adapter);

$rowset = $table->select(function (\Zend\Db\Sql\Select $select) {
    $select->where(array(
        new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression("MATCH(column) AGAINST ('testing')")
    ));
});
```